# Weird start-stop-daemon behaviour?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon, pid

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
for s in sys.argv:
    print(s)
```

Now I execute:

```
sudo start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/test.pid --make-pidfile /var/run/test.pid --user max --exec /home/max/Dokumente/test.py
```

And the output is:

```
/home/max/Dokumente/test.py
/var/run/test.pid
```

My Question is: why does it use the pidfile as an argument for my script and is there a way to prevent that?

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read the man page more carefuly. The `--make-pidfile` takes no arguments, it is a flag:

```
   -m, --make-pidfile
          Used when starting a program that does not  create  its  own  pid  file.  This  option  will  make
          start-stop-daemon  create the file referenced with --pidfile and place the pid into it just before
          executing the process. Note, the file will not be removed when stopping the program.   NOTE:  This
          feature  may  not  work  in all cases. Most notably when the program being executed forks from its
          main process. Because of this, it is usually only  useful  when  combined  with  the  --background
          option.
```

So, if the command is run as

```
$ sudo start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/test.pid \ 
 --make-pidfile /var/run/test.pid --user max --exec /bin/echo
```

The second mention of `/var/run/test.pid` is not captured by any options and so is passed as an argument to the executable being called by `--exec`. That's why it's printed when you have your script print its arguments. The solution is to simply not give any argument to `--make-pidfile`:

```
$ sudo start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /var/run/test.pid \ 
 --make-pidfile --user max --exec /bin/echo
```

Kudos to the OP who [solved it him/herself](https://superuser.com/questions/651940/weird-start-stop-daemon-behaviour/651971?noredirect=1#comment820678_651971) but had already accepted my answer.

Comment: Actually I found my problem: the --make-pidfile option is using the argument of --pidfile. So there is one argument left, which is (no idea, why) given to the script. The funny thing is that most examples with --make-pidfile, I found, gave it an argument, which seems to be wrong syntax.